# Can't assign to object in linked list

Tags: c++, c++11

Head and tail are getting populated, and print out the values, but nodePtr stays empty for some reason. When I debug in VS2015, head and tail number is getting populated, while field this stays empty

Here's Linked_List

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_
#define _LINKED_LIST_

#include <iostream>

class LinkedList
{
public:

    struct Node
    {
        int number;
        Node * next;
        Node() : number(NULL), next(NULL) {};
        Node(int number_, Node * next_ = NULL)
        {
            number = number_;
            next = next_;
        }
    }*head, *tail, *nodePtr;


LinkedList();
~LinkedList();

void add(int num);

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list);

private:
    int size;
};

#endif // _LINKED_LIST_
```

Implementation file

```
include "linkedlist.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), nodePtr(NULL) 
{
    nodePtr = new Node();
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node * curr, *temp;
    curr = head;
    temp = head;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = curr;
    }
}


void LinkedList::add(int num)
{
    Node * newNode = new Node();
    newNode->number = num;
    cout << newNode->number;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        tail = newNode;
        size++;
    }
    //cout << nodePtr->number; //empty, or some random
    //just some tests
    cout << head->number;
    if (head->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->next->number;
    }
    cout << tail->number;
    cout << endl;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, LinkedList & list)
{
    out << list.nodePtr->number << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    LinkedList list;

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    cout << list;


    cout << "Press 1: ";
    cin >> num;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OmidCompSCI just an accident, it's not the main problem though. I edited it though, so thanks!)

Comment: What do you _want_ it to do?  The only time you change its value is in your `LinkedList` constructor, where you allocate a new node.  What is the meaning of `nodePtr`?  Only you know that.  If you expect its value to represent something, then you must actually modify it somewhere.

Comment: @paddy I'm trying to have a linked list of ints: 1->2->3 etc. 
I feel I'm missing something really obvious, yet can't see it.
nodePtr should be that linked list which holds the values

Comment: Off topic: `size` is left uninitialized by the `LinkedList` constructor and it looks like it is used later. This be bad Juju.

Comment: Okay, let me be more explicit.  Your question puzzles over this: _"but nodePtr stays empty for some reason"_.  The reason is you never modify it.  So my question asks what you expect to happen, since you never modify the value of `nodePtr` after `LinkedList` is constructed.

Comment: _"nodePtr should be that linked list which holds the values"_ -- no, this is what `head` is.  It's the _first_ node in your list.  To print out the whole list, you must visit every node from `head` to `tail`, one at a time, by following their `next` pointers.  As your code currently stands, `nodePtr` is some other list that contains a single node.

Comment: @paddy will I modify it if in implementation code I will not create new Node, but will `this->nodePtr->number = num` ?

Comment: But why would you do that?  Again, _what is nodePtr for_?  Your list is contained between `head` and `tail`.  What do you hope to gain by changing a value in `nodePtr`?  Do you want it to store the value that you most recently added?  Even though that's already stored in `tail`?

Comment: @paddy it should contain number. There is list of nodes, each contains nubmer and pointer to the next node. So when I try to print the nodes out, I can access each individual node and get that number

Comment: _"I feel I'm missing something really obvious"_ -- yes ;)  Okay, I've ascertained finally that `nodePtr` is your solution to not understanding something fundamental about lists.  I've provided an answer which shows you how to use a list.  You don't need `nodePtr` at all.

Comment: @paddy I work on 2 more different projects, and in one of them I need to use linked list inside linked list, where something like nodePtr will be needed (I think). This is not the actual problem, I just made it so I could understand fundamental problem.Thanks again

Comment: Or you could just use `std::list`...  You know, `std::list<std::list<int>>`.  That's kinda weird though.  Cos it flattens out to a single list.

Comment: @paddy vectors would work too, but I need to use "own-created" lists;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a fundamental concept here.  `nodePtr` is not some magical node that knows about all your other nodes, or knows about linked lists, or can be used to print all their numbers.

When you do this:

```
out << list.nodePtr->number << endl;
```

All you are doing is outputting the value that you initialized when you allocated a new `Node` and stored a pointer in `nodePtr`:

```
nodePtr = new Node();
```

That called the default constructor for `Node` which set `nodePtr->number` to zero.  (side-note, you initialized it to `NULL`, not `0` -- you should not mix integer types with pointer types, so change it to initialize the value to 0).

Its value stays 0 because you never modify it.  And `nodePtr` always points at that single node because you never modified `nodePtr`.

What you're actually wanting to do is print out your list.  Let me suggest the normal way to do this, by starting at `head` and following the node linkages:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const LinkedList & list)
{
    for( Node *node = list.head; node != nullptr; node = node->next )
    {
        out << node->number << std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

And finally, I suggest you remove `nodePtr` from your class completely.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
How would I modify nodePtr though?(if it's possible even)

Comment: ARRGH haven't we now come to the understanding that `nodePtr` is redundant?  Or are you trolling me? ;)  I do have better things to do, so please don't troll me.

Comment: @illia Answering that question with a question, *why would you want to*?

Comment: @paddy ;DDDD

Thanks man, I really appreciate it. I now see where I misunderstood and messed up)

Answer (score 0):

You only use nodePtr in the constructor, you never change it's values.

Comment: Doesn't add function modifies it?

Comment: The add function never references it in any way.  What line do you think modifies `nodePtr`?

Comment: No, it's used in that function. That function only modifies head, tail and size, but nodePtr is not used at all. The only way nodePtr could be modify is creating a new instance of the LinkedList class and not creating a new Node.

Comment: @TrentP you're suggesting that I should `nodePtr = newNode` at the end of the add?

Comment: No, that would cause a memory leak.

Comment: @RavenH. deleting `nodePtr = new Node()` in the constructor, will it work?

Comment: No, what do you need nodePtr to do?

Comment: ^ this is the fundamental question I started in the question comments section, and never had an answer for.